# Vaadin OptionGroup caption location

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to get an `OptionGroup` to have the labels next to them, on the right hand side like normal radio buttons in every other UI I have ever used, instead of underneath them.  I do not see anything in the API regarding how to change the layout of this?  Anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Have you added the `OptionGroup` to a layout? I have an `OptionGroup` in a `HorizontalLayout` and the descriptions appear on the right of the checkbox.

Comment: But then all the radio buttons are aligned horizontally as with text.
I need it to have the radio button on first line with text to the right, and the subsequent radio buttons under it, vertically, with text to the right.

Comment: I am using the arrangement I described. I have a list of check boxes arranged vertically, with the descriptions to the right of each check box.

Comment: really?  I did the following, and same thing, text under the radio button
HorizontalLayout hzl = new HorizontalLayout();
affiliation = new OptionGroup();
affiliation.addItem("AFC");
affiliation.addItem("NFC");
hzl.addComponent(affiliation);
mainLayout.addComponent(hzl);

Comment: Not sure if there is some difference in the behaviour as I have multiple select (checkbox) and not single select (radio).

Comment: Even my checkboxes, the text is under them, and not to the right.  I cant for the life of me get those to change either.
I hacked that form with no caption, and put labels next to each, just to get something deployed.  But that cant be how to really do this...

Comment: What type of layout is `mainLayout` and to what parent is it attached (another layout, Application/UI) ? Did you set any styles to the layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:
Add these lines to your css

```
.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal .v-select-option {
display: inline-block;
}

.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal {
white-space: nowrap;
}

.v-select-optiongroup-horizontal
.v-select-option.v-radiobutton {
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

And call

`group.setStyleName("horizontal");`

where group is the OptionGroup object.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you inherited some styles that display the text like that?
Did you try to call **hzl.setSizeUndefined()**? Or maybe playing with the width (setWidth()).